# Kepler's books: Mysterium Cosmographicum, Astronomia Nova, and Harmonices Mundi

Tags: discrete-mathematics, contest-math, math-history, mathematical-astronomy

I have started doing some research on Kepler and I have come across these three books that he wrote: Mysterium Cosmographicum, Astronomia Nova, and Harmonices Mundi.

I was wondering if anyone is familiar with some particular mathematical problems from these books. I have been trying to get my hands on some translated copies of the books and look for some particular math problems that he has solved in them. I am looking for something that isn't really talked about that much.

I hope this is an appropriate question to ask on this forum otherwise if someone can kindly point me to the right forum that would be wonderful.

Comment: Trying at german newsgroup   de.sci.mathematik might help

Comment: You know that they are written in Latin? You know his three laws of orbital motion?

Comment: @Somos Yes I am aware that the original language is Latin I am looking for translations that have been past down. Also, yes I do know the three laws of orbital motion but I was looking for something that isn't really talked about that much. Does that make any sense?

Comment: It makes sense to place this kind of missing specific requests in the original question. Please do so now..

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonices_Mundi   (last reference)

Comment: @Narasimham just to clarify are you talking about the " At the V&A: Tim Watts' Musically and Dramatically Compelling Kepler's Trial"?

Comment: No, am not wiser than wiki :) .. actually this ref too is given there in red.

Comment: Are you aware that [Mysterium Cosmographicum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mysterium_Cosmographicum) is mainly about the relationship between planets' orbits and regular solids ?

Comment: A.Koyré's [Astronomical revolution](https://books.google.it/books?id=l0YRAZz2yU0C&pg=PA127) has a detailed chapters dedicated to *Mysterium*.

Comment: See also Bruce Stephenson, [The Music of the Heavens : Kepler's Harmonic Astronomy (1994)](https://books.google.it/books?id=cEsABAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) as well as J.V. Field, [Kepler's Geometrical Cosmology (2014)](https://books.google.it/books?id=gKJWDgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you so very much for that!! Extremely helpful!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overall some amazing stuff that are being talked to in the three specific books are:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mysterium_Cosmographicum

https://books.google.it/books?id=l0YRAZz2yU0C&pg=PA127#v=onepage&q&f=false

https://books.google.it/books?id=cEsABAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false

https://books.google.it/books?id=gKJWDgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false